# Error messages: local or direct from server API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, restful-architecture, convention

Is it generally regarded as safe to display error strings directly from a server?

I'm working on an iOS app that directly communicates with a (rather weak) REST API. The sever sometimes will return an error code and message in JSON format.

I've been handling these errors by displaying MY OWN local error strings for 'known' error types. Error codes that I don't handle will display my general error message.

My colleague is suggesting I simply display the error message directly from the sever, to allow for faster API iteration (we own the API).

Isn't this extremely insecure? It breaks MVC convention, for sure. **Is it bad for any reason aside from localization?**

Answer (score 2):

Letting the server provide error message text is generally a bad idea.  As you point out, it mixes UI and back-end logic on the server and makes localization harder.